# Where to store images in iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS development. I have created a simple iOS app where I have many buttons with images inside. Also cells of UITableView in my application contains images.

Up to now I have put all images for buttons and cells in the "Assets.xcassets" folder. The images can also be accessed if I locate all images in separate directory (let say "Images" folder).

Where is the correct place to locate images? As far as I know in "Assets.xcassets" app logo, tab bar icons can be located, but I don't know is it allowed to store all images in that folder.

Comment: There's a images xcassets folder right ?

Comment: In xcode there is Assets.xcassets folder, but not images xcassets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of xcassets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441935/use-of-xcassets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you should use assets for all static images you have in an app. Assets were introduced for a better handling of images with different resolutions for different devices (like @2x, @3x for retina devices). When user installs the app not all versions of the same image are downloaded but only that one that fits the best user's device. So your app will take less space which is good. Also assets are more convenient if you have several versions with different resolutions for the same image.

If you want you can place images in several assets. To add a new asset go to File > New > File and choose Asset Catalog in Resource section.

Answer (score 7):

You can store any resource you like in the `Assets.xcassets` folder. Simply drag and drop the images into the `Assets.xcassets` folder and use them. There is no limit to what type of asset you put in the `Assets.xcassets` catalog. Of course, you can add a new asset catalog. It can be found in `File > New > File`, scrolling down to `Resource` and then clicking `Asset Catalog`. It acts the same as `Assets.xcassets` and the usage is the same.

[image: asset catalog]

For example, if you put an image called foo in an asset catalog called `Bar.xcassets`, you can still use

```
UIImage("foo")
```

without specifying the name of your catalog.